# Add SOAP/WSDL Web Service reference at runtime

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, wsdl, vpn

Has anyone successfully added a Soap Web Service to a C# App at runtime?

This is required because the C# app is going to be deployed to a host connected to a VPN. The Soap Web Service is another host in the VPN. (We cannot install Visual Studio on the deployment host). Therefore, we cannot add the reference in our development machines. We are developing against a fake service.

Comment: You only need to get the URL from the config file.

Comment: Assuming the service is the same, but it might not.

Comment: So you're going to call it all through reflection?

Comment: Once we figure out what methods it exposes and what they return we will code it normally, but until then yes we'll use reflection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can generate proxy classes from the web service url.

read the following article.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa529578.aspx

This way you do not need to add reference to the web service.

Also what do you mean by adding reference at runtime. You can add reference to your local development PC and then deploy the code to the host PC. There is no need to add reference again when your project is deployed to third party server.

Comment: I cannot access the reference from outside the VPN (Our dev machines are outside the VPN). The Web Service is inside the VPN.

Comment: Can you take SVCUTIL.exe to deployment host and on the VPN ?
It's the utility which can generated the proxy class which you can use.