# Dynamic Soap in Rest Service

Tags: java, spring-boot, http, soap, apache-camel

I am facing trouble finding if my idea is applicable or not.
First/ Can we add soap service at run time?
Second/ Can we implement Soap over Http and without WSDL file?

I want to use it with apache camel routing, on Route for http and another for Soap.

Yes you can or no you can't.

Comment: for the first question:this one may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18528826/add-soap-wsdl-web-service-reference-at-runtime

for the second one: this one may help you if i understood you wright
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5389568/how-to-use-soap-ui-without-wsdl

Comment: Let me explain more, I want to have dynamic soap api generated at run time with java and apache camel.